# How to transfer the data from Chrome Browser Console onto C# file

Tags: c#, json, node.js, kinect, console.log

We are getting joint data in JSON Objects format. The data is streaming live on the Chrome Console as you can see in the picture.

How do we take this data (from the Chrome Console) and send it over to a C# file on the computer in real-time?

*From Console: JSON Object data from kinectv2*

[image: From Console: JSON Object data from kinectv2]

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? 
Are you just trying to write a file ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file ) , Are you trying to use the data in a c# app? try to receive with a websocket ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server )

Comment: Yes we are trying to implement the data into a C# application that display skeleton frames from multiple kinects. Data is being generated and must be streamed in real-time. So far we are getting the data from a kinect into the Chrome Console as JSON objects, do you know how we can take that data and use it in a C# application?

Comment: Can you just get the data directly in the C# app?, that would be the simplest, are you doing your data generation in the browser? Could that be migrated to c#

Comment: The code that we are using to get the data is in JavaScript. So its being transferred, sent over and collected in the Chrome Browsers. Ideally, yes, the data directly goes into the C# application. We have been looking for some kind of C# function/code that can obtain the data from the browsers and then have it feeding real time in the C# app. This is the heart of our issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some basic c# websocket code, it doesnt have to convert the data it receives to a string. I was just testing some stuff

C# simple websocket connection

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Websocket_listen _listener;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _listener = new Websocket_listen("127.0.0.1", 13000);
        _listener.StringReceived += _listener_StringReceived;
        _listener.Start();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _running = false;
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    private void _listener_StringReceived(string received)
    {
    }
}

public class Websocket_listen
{
    public readonly int port = 13000;
    public readonly IPAddress localAddr;

    private TcpListener server = null;
    private TcpClient client = null;
    private NetworkStream stream = null;
    private bool connected = false;
    private byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
    private byte[] _last_key = new byte[4];
    private int _last_message_length;
    private bool read_more_message;
    private Thread _current_thread;
    private bool _running = true;
    private int _received = 0;
    private StringBuilder _results = new StringBuilder();

    public event Action<string> StringReceived = null;

    public Websocket_listen(string ipaddress, int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress);
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
    }

    public void _running_loop()
    {

        while (_running)
        {
            try
            {

                server.Server.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
                server.Server.SendTimeout = 5000;
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                stream = client.GetStream();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                continue;
            }

            while (_running)
            {
                try
                {
                    try
                    {

                        l.AcquireWriterLock(-1);
                        if (messsages.Count > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messsages[0]);
                            //byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Connected to " + Environment.MachineName);
                            Array.Copy(msg, 0, bytes, 2, msg.Length);
                            bytes[0] = 0x81;
                            bytes[1] = (byte)msg.Length;
                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(bytes, 0, msg.Length + 2);
                            messsages.RemoveAt(0);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        l.ReleaseWriterLock();
                    }

                }
                catch { }

                try
                {
                    _received = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (_received == 0)
                    continue;

                if (!connected)
                {
                    _is_connection();
                    continue;
                }

                if (!_parse_message())
                    break;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private bool _parse_message()
    {
        int offset = 0;
        int message_length = 0;
        if (read_more_message)
        {
            _last_message_length -= bytes.Length;
            message_length = _last_message_length;
            if (message_length < bytes.Length)
                message_length += 8;
        }
        else
        {
            _results.Clear();
            var trigger = bytes[0];
            var magic_byte = bytes[1];
            bool is_text = (0x1 & trigger) != 0;
            bool is_fin = (0x80 & trigger) != 0;

            if (trigger == 0x88)
            {
                connected = false;
                return false;
            }
            /*
            text = 0x81
            binary = 0x82
            close 0x88
            ping 0x89
            pong -0x8A
            */


            if (!is_fin)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!is_text)
            {
                return true;
            }

            //If the second byte minus 128 is between 0 and 125, this is the length of message. 
            //If it is 126, the following 2 bytes (16-bit unsigned integer), if 127, the following 8 bytes (64-bit unsigned integer) are the length.
            var r = magic_byte - 128;
            var key_starts_at = 0;
            if (r <= 125)
            {
                key_starts_at = 2;
                message_length = r;
            }
            else if (r == 126)
            {
                key_starts_at = 4;
                message_length = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { bytes[3], bytes[2] }, 0);
            }
            else if (r == 127)
            {
                key_starts_at = 10;
                for (var m = 7; m >= 0; --m)
                {
                    message_length += bytes[m] << (8 * (7 - m));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // not documented
            }
            //// because its encoded
            _last_message_length = message_length;
            Array.Copy(bytes, key_starts_at, _last_key, 0, 4);

            offset = key_starts_at + 4;

        }
        for (var mx = 0; mx < message_length && offset + mx < bytes.Length; ++mx)
        {
            bytes[offset + mx] = (byte)(bytes[offset + mx] ^ _last_key[mx % 4]);
        }

        var new_result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, offset, Math.Min(message_length, bytes.Length - offset));
        _results.Append(new_result);
        read_more_message = message_length > bytes.Length;

        if (!read_more_message)
        {
            try
            {
                StringReceived?.Invoke(_results.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void _is_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, _received);

            if (!new Regex("^GET").IsMatch(data))
                return;
            Byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + Environment.NewLine
                + "Connection: Upgrade" + Environment.NewLine
                + "Upgrade: websocket" + Environment.NewLine
                + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(
                    SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(data).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
                        )
                    )
                ) + Environment.NewLine
                + Environment.NewLine);

            stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
            connected = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _running = false;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Start listening for client requests.
        server.Start();


        _current_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_running_loop));
        _current_thread.Start();

    }
    ReaderWriterLock l = new ReaderWriterLock();
    List<string> messsages = new List<string>();
    internal void Send(string msg)
    {
     try
        {
            l.AcquireWriterLock(-1);

            messsages.Add(msg);
        }   
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            l.ReleaseWriterLock();

        }
    }
}
```

not a very robust javascript simple websocket to connect to c# with the same port

```
try {
        var isopen = false;
        connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:13000');

        // When the connection is open, send some data to the server
        connection.onopen = function () {
            isopen = true;
          connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
          $('#open_messages').html("connection made\r\n<br>");
          $('#socket_errors').html("");
        };

        // Log errors
        connection.onerror = function (error) {
          console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);
          $('#socket_errors').html(error.currentTarget.url + " failed\r\n<br><button id=\"reconnect\">Try to connect</button>");
        };

        // Log messages from the server
        connection.onmessage = function (e) {
          console.log('Server: ', e);
          $('#messages').append(e.data + "\r\n<br>");
        };

        connection.onclose = function(x) {
            console.log('closed ', x);
          $('#open_messages').html("Disconnected\r\n<br>");
          $('#socket_errors').html("<button id=\"reconnect\">Connect</button>");
        };

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
}
```

That should get you started sending data back and forth, but will probably need extra exception handling.
Not sure if sending strings across is efficient, by you could probably change the data later.

Comment: Would this work if I need to send the data to another computer over the same network?

Comment: Yes, you may have to add some exceptions to the windows firewall to add an exception for the port you pick